# How to bind values in select attribute?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am developing web application for that i am using codeigniter-3 framework,i have one hardcoded dropdown in view file that is working fine as i expected.in my listing page one edit option is there i have passed the data from controller to the view file for binding the data for editing it's working fine except `select` dropdown can you please help me to fix the issue...?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputName1">Movie Type</label>
    <select name="m_type" id="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">No Selected</option>
       <option value="1">Horror</option>
        <option value="2">Comedy</option>
        <option value="3">Romance</option>
    </select>
</div>
//it's working fine for  Book Qty
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputName1">Book Quantity</label>
<input type="text" name="b_qty" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $res[0]->book_quantity; ?>" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="">
</div>
```

**dump**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#32 (13) {
    ["id"]=> '11'
    ["tank_type"]=> "1"

  }
}
```

i want to bind the Horror in the edit page dropdown by default in this case.

Comment: Do you mean (active or selected) option in dropdown by default when value ='Horror '

Comment: By default it's displayed as No selected instead of that one it should  be `selected as Horror`

Comment: If you want Horror to be selected, just be sure to use `selected` in the `<option>`. That is, `<option value="1" selected>Horror</option>`. It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: @JuanMendes,in edit page the value should bind in the dropdown and remaining options also will come for modifying

Answer (score 0):

Use `selected` attribute to do that or jQuery Code

```js
jQuery('#m_type').val('1').trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="m_type" id="m_type" class="form-control">
    <option value="">No Selected</option>
    <option value="1">Horror</option>
    <option value="2">Comedy</option>
    <option value="3">Romance</option>
</select>
```

```
<select class="form-control" id="customer_id" name="customer_id">

    <?php foreach ( $array as $item ){ ?>
    
       <option value="<?php echo $item->id ?>"<?php echo($item->id=='1')?'selected':''; ?>><?php echo $item->label; ?></option>
    
    <?php }?>
    
    </select>
```

Comment: i put selected for all the options it's coming the last one in this scenario it's coming  `Romance`

Comment: Note:- it's a dynamic data so i can't able to put selected one particular field

Comment: Try to use jQuery code

Comment: There's no need for JS here.

Comment: Try to use condition in loop

Comment: @Abdo-Host,it is working but remaining options are not coming inside the dropdown.this is edit page it should bind the value it's saved and displayed it's working fine but remaining options also it will show right for updating or modyfing